# Plugin/SDF problem; unable to find or open sdf file

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, I am trying to create my first Gazebo plugin. I tried to follow this tutorial - [link](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/plugins/overview), and this is the result (Gazebo was installed as pre-compiled binaries on Ubuntu 12.04.):

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Error [parser.cc:69] Unable to find or open SDF file[]
Error [Server.cc:247] Unable to initialize sdf

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2804/plugin/sdf-problem;-unable-to-find-or-open-sdf-file/) by [bot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/345/bot/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-05-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Davinci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/108/davinci/) on 2013-05-13**:
Having the same error while executing: gzsdf print model.urdfError [parser.cc:69] Unable to find or open SDF file[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am going to answer my own question :). I forgot this part of installation: [quick start](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/tutorials_quickstart). This line solved problem for me:

```
source /usr/share/gazebo[version]/setup.sh
```

---

Originally posted by [bot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/345/bot/) with karma: 46 on 2013-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1